# Should I answer my own question if I'm not 100% happy with my answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[How can I replicate the style of images produced by an old Finepix digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59778/how-can-i-replicate-the-style-of-images-produced-by-an-old-finepix-digital-camer)

There have been two upvotes but no answer to my question.
I think I know the procedure how to get "half-way" results (of what I want) but I personally wouldn't accept them as a valid answer.

What shoud I do?

1. Wait for a few more days (do nothing)
2. Edit my question and post details about my current approach
3. Answer my own question (while my answer will be partially correct)

As for 2) or 3): I hope someone might improve/correct my procedure to get better results.

Comment: What Philip said... Though if a follow-on answer cites yours as part of what they're doing, leave it behind to maintain clarity. If, after a while, you also figure it out, just edit your original answer and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering your own question *but not accepting your answer* seems like entirely the right action here. That gives information which is better than the currently available set of zero answers, but makes it (moderately) clear that your solution is only a half-way house.

If you want to make it clearer that this is only a partial solution, call that out explicitly at the top of your answer. If somebody does take your procedure and expands upon it to produce a better result, you can always delete your answer later.